# Push change set from sandbox to sandbox

Tags: sandbox, change-set

Can I connect two of my sandboxes and push change sets from one to the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the sandboxes are connected to the same production org, and assuming that you have set up the deployment connections between the two sandboxes, yes you can deploy change sets between them.

Comment: If the sandboxes are not connected to the same production org, an alternative to use would be the force.com migration toolkit (an ANT library) for deploying metadata between environments